The method 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' isn't defined for the class 'Tensor'
Im using tflite_flutter-0.10.4 but UnmodifiableUint8ListView was deprecated from typed_data some while ago:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html
When i try to run my code in android i get this:
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/tflite_flutter-0.10.4/lib/src/tensor.dart:58:12: Error: The method 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' isn't defined for the class 'Tensor'.


'Tensor' is from 'package:tflite_flutter/src/tensor.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/tflite_flutter-0.10.4/lib/src/tensor.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'.
return UnmodifiableUint8ListView(

any fix??

I posted the solution here, just check it and thank me later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79238296/15721679

In my case, I changed the getter method of 'tensor.dart' file as shown below
  /// Underlying data buffer as bytes.
  Uint8List get data {
    final data = cast<Uint8>(tfLiteTensorData(_tensor));
    return Uint8List.view(
        data.asTypedList(tfLiteTensorByteSize(_tensor)).buffer);
  }

After flutter updated to 3.24.0, I guess the 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' type is no longer supported. So need to circumvent the type that can be recognized.
+For additional, I checked the github issue and followed the answer, but in my case didn't work. So I changed the code like above.

I am getting this error on Flutter 3.22.3 • channel stable and tflite_flutter-0.9.5, I'd imagine if I still used a previous version of flutter, I shouldnt get this error, right? How is it still showing up...

This is actually due to an upstream change in Dart, not Flutter.

Solution from the GitHub repository. Thanks to the User @ptgms
I have a temporary fix until it is fixed in the package. Change the package locally in your pub-cache. In the conflicting line, change the getter to this:
Uint8List get data {
    final data = cast<Uint8>(tfliteBinding.TfLiteTensorData(_tensor));
    return data.asTypedList(tfliteBinding.TfLiteTensorByteSize(_tensor)).asUnmodifiableView();
  }

